# Regex Problem - Getting what's inside the first span

Tags: regex

I have some trouble with regex and php here:

```
   <span style="color: blue">word1</span> word by word by word <span style="color: red">word</span>
```

I'm trying to get word1 out. Is the regex the best way though? Need to process around 70 sencences like this.

UPDATE

```
$one = '<span style="color: blue">word1</span> word by word by word <span style="color: red">word</span>';
preg_match('/<span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>/',$one);
echo $one;
```

Don't works, it outputs the same. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: 1) What flavour of Regex / language are you using? 2) Are all of the sentences guaranteed to be in that quite straight forward format of open span tag immediately followed by target word?

Comment: 1) php, 2) true, but of course the word is different each time.

Comment: But really, don't use regex to parse HTML.  :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following regex, capture the first result and discard the rest (if you just want to get the first result).

```
 <span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>
```

See it in action: http://rubular.com/r/ateGVj5PCu

---

**WARNING:** [Regex is not suited for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). If your code is more complicated than this, I strongly recommend using an (X)HTML parser

Comment: +1 for "Regex is not suited for parsing HTML." Truer words have not been spoken.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '<span style="color: blue">word1</span> word by word by word <span style="color: red">word</span>
';

var myArray = str.match(/<span[^>]+>(\w+)<\/span>/);
```

**Return**
myArray[1] = "word1";

Comment: What if the opening tag is just `<span>`? What if the contents are empty? What if the words contain non-word characters?

Comment: In my case, there's never just <span> (color varies from red and blue), no empty ones, but sometimes they contain two words.